# Why does L_BFGS_B optimization skip to extreme range of viable solutions in this instance?

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I appreciate this is a very specific question!

To aid in explanation: I am exploring the use of a linear optimizer to demonstrate how sharp 'cliffs' in a function surface can lead to non-optimal solutions. Reproducible code in R as follows:

```
library(glmnet)
library(mice)


# Load data
df <- read.csv(paste0('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets',
                      '/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv'), header = F)

colnames(df) <- c('Pregnancies', 'Glucose', 'BloodPressure', 'SkinThickness',
                  'Insulin', 'BMI', 'DiabetesPedigreeFunction', 'Age', 'Outcome')


set.seed(40)

# Impute 0 (missing) values for columns 2 through 8 (Glucose - Age)
df[2:8] <- lapply(df[2:8], function(x) replace(x, x %in% 0, NA))
micedf <- mice(df)
df <- complete(micedf)

# Create train/test split
sample_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(df))
train_index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = sample_size)
train <- df[train_index,]
test  <- df[-train_index,]

# Generate model matrix format for glmnet
x <- as.matrix(train[,1:8])
y <- train$Outcome

# Fitting function
GLM_tune <- function(alpha) {
    set.seed(40)
    cvglmnet <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(x, y, nfolds = 5, family = "binomial",
                                  alpha = alpha, type.measure = "auc",
                                  parallel = F)

    return (cvglmnet$cvm[cvglmnet$lambda == cvglmnet$lambda.1se])    }
```

Now, if I enter a value somewhere between 0 and 1 as follows:

```
optim(par = 0.9, fn = GLM_tune, lower = 0, upper = 1, 
      control = list(fnscale = -1, trace=3), method = c("L-BFGS-B"))

# >> $par = 0.86
```

The optimizer climbs to a local maxima - which I've tested by exploring the whole surface area using:

```
surf <- data.frame(alpha = 0, auc = 0)   
for (a in seq(from=0, to=1000)) {
    surf[a+1,1] <- a/1000
    surf[a+1,2] <- GLM_tune(a/1000)
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=surf, size = 1.2, color = "black", aes(alpha, auc))
```

**However**, when I set alpha = 1 as the starting point, the algorithm shifts to alpha = 0 as the second iteration then exits as a 'final' solution:

```
optim(par = 1, fn = GLM_tune, lower = 0, upper = 1, 
      control = list(fnscale = -1, trace=3), method = c("L-BFGS-B"))

# >> $par = 0
```

Why would this be the case? Clearly I don't fully understand the algorithm, but I assumed the default stepping was 0.001 in the optim function (see ndeps) - so why would it go to the opposite extreme as the next step?  Am I missing a crucial parameter that should be set for these problems?

Comment: (I don't use R and ignored your code:) L-BGS-B has no fixed step-size. It's using [line-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions).

Comment: I see; but I'm still unclear why the step-size it decides upon is (in effect) the entire range when alpha starts at 1, but doesn't do this when alpha starts at 0.9.  I believe what you say, I just don't understand why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the path of the objective function it is clear that it has many local maxima, and hence, a gradient based optimization algorithm like the "L-BFGS-B" is **not** suitable to find the global maximum.
[image]

Furthermore, with my R (3.6),

```
optim(par = 1, fn = GLM_tune, lower = 0, upper = 1, 
      control = list(fnscale = -1, trace=3), method = c("L-BFGS-B"))$par
## [1] 1
```

returns `1` and not `0` as you indicate.

To understand why it converges to `1`, we can look at the optimization path of the "L-BFGS-B" algorithm. I prefer to use the R package **optimParallel** https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=optimParallel for this purpose. I am the author of the package:

```
library("optimParallel")
cl <- makeCluster(2); setDefaultCluster(cl=cl)
clusterExport(cl, c("x", "y")) # export implicitly used values
optimParallel(par = 1, fn = GLM_tune,
              lower = 0, upper = 1, 
              control = list(fnscale = -1),
              parallel = list(optimParallel.loginfo=TRUE))$loginfo 
##      step       par1         fn        gr1 
## 1.0000000  1.0000000 -0.8215854  0.0000000
```

We see that the gradient at `1` is `0`. Hence, this it is no surprise that the algorithm stops at `1`.

We can check the calculation of the approximate gradient with

```
ndeps <- 0.001  # the default value
(GLM_tune(1) - GLM_tune(1-ndeps))/ndeps
## [1] 0
```

Note if `1` would not be the upper bound, `optim()` was using a central difference gradient approximation. Something like

```
(GLM_tune(1+ndeps) - GLM_tune(1-ndeps))/(2*ndeps)
```

Comment: Many thanks Florian; I'm obviously going to try out your package now given the plug!  I've re-tested in both 3.6 and 3.5.2; I get par = 1 in v 3.6 but I get par = 0 in v 3.5.2.  Interesting.  ^I realise this method is not optimal for a global maxima, this question came out of a blog post comparing genetic algorithms as a solver. It was worth clarifying though, so thanks, just in case someone else trips across this in the future.